# When should I free memory used in a loop in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is probably a pretty basic question, but I think it's important that I know the answer. I have a very long for loop in which I use a certain pointer only near the beginning. Is it better to allocate the required memory outside the loop and free it when the loop is finished, or to repeatedly allocate the memory at the beginning of the loop and free it as soon as I'm finished with the pointer? I assume the latter case is the better of the two, but I don't really know how much power goes into allocating memory each time, so I wanted to check before proceeding.

Comment: It depends. On what your code is doing. Only you can see it.

Comment: If you can easily reuse the buffer than it would be better to perform only one allocation.  But yeah, we need a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends precisely on where's your performance bottleneck.

If you need it to be as fast as you can, and every single millisecond matters, then your best shot would be not to allocate it every time.

However, it spends memory. If memory is a huge issue to you, and every single byte allocated is painful, then you should free the memory ASAP - and thus allocating it exactly when you need, several times if needed.

Usually, when you're writing C code, both statements are true. So, it's a trade-off: you have to check with loss is less costly to your particular situation.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer and this is in fact a quite complex problem.

It depends on many things, allocation size, memory fragmentation, optimization, ...

If you have enough memory, allocate and free outside the loop (because concerning speed, dynamic allocations are bad )

If not, allocate just before you need memory and free as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the allocation is only strictly used local to the loop, then I would start with the assumption that the allocation/deallocation should occur within the loop.  This is a similar concept to the idea that variables used only within a loop's body should be declared local to the loop.

However, this is just a starting point. There are several valid reasons for making the allocation outside the loop and deallocating when the loop is complete. Some of these reasons might be:

- performance - alloc/dealloc is expensive. Churn from repeated alloc/dealloc operations is a valid reason to move these outside the loop. For many loops this probably doesn't matter too much, but it definitely could be a valid concern.
- correctness - if the loop might terminate early then it might be best to move the deallocation outside where it might be easier to account for all ways the loop can exit. Note that in C++, RAII support might encourage the opposite strategy.